# undefined method id for TrueClass Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

```
  def can_save(board,role)
    if ar_user = already_registered?(email) || user = self.save
      Participant.make(ar_user||user, board, role)
    end
    user
  end
```

I do this rspec test on it:

```
it "should return the user if the user is not already registered" do
     lambda do
      user = @new_user.can_save(@board, "Manager")
    end.should change(User,:count).by(1)
   end
```

I get this error:

```
  undefined method `id' for true:TrueClass
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`save` method returns true or false, not a saved instance of object.

Comment: Thanks I found that if I wrap (the user=self.save) in brackets it worked but don't know why.

Comment: If first part of expression `already_registered?(email)` return not nil object, the second is not calculdated, so all works fine.